# How to remove unwanted commit and merge

Tags: git

I've the following sequence of commits:

```
A---B---D---E---G---H---
     \     / \
      C---/   F---
```

Commit D introduces improper change and merge commit E forwards it to F and G.
I'd like to remove D and E commits comletely.
What can do to have:

```
A---B---C---G---H---
         \
          F---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are revising history here.  If that history isn't present on any other repos, that's fine, otherwise make sure you know what you're doing.

checkout a branch named `my_better_history` with `HEAD` at `C`
    git checkout -b my_better_history C

Bring in the commits you want:
    git cherry-pick G H

Check your work. If your original branch was called `master`, you could do `git diff-tool master` to make sure the states are identical.  If everything is good you can make your new history your official history.  Let's say you started with branch `master`, then you could do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard C #now your master is back to the common history point.
git merge my_better_history
```

Now master will have the desired history.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I forgot to mention, all that is on my local repo.

Answer (score 0):

- you need to reset --hard to B_COMMIT_HASH
- then [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) G and H commits
- afret this you will be [deateched](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit) to you will need to push your brache with flag -f

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete answer you will have to figure out the rest.. but HTH

**SOLUTION 1:**

If you are ok with revising hostory - !! on some workflows this is very bad.. on some it is not - like when you have your local branch etc.. but **be careful** !!

You can use nice tool interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i HASH_OF_B
```

You will see probably something like this:

```
pick H
pick G
pick F
pick D <-- remove this line
pick C 
pick A
```

And you will just delete the ones which are D (hope it will work this way when you have multiple children etc) - **be very careful**, I am not sure what this will do..

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
git revert C
git revert D
```

and you are safe - not changing history etc..

You will have to do this on both branches - on the F branch and also on the H branch - not sure what happens to the merge commit if you introduced any merge changes regarding D..